# Debian install says "The CD_ROM does not seem to contain a valid 'Release' file" when installing from usb

Tags: debian, usb, debian-installer

I have a YUMI multiboot installer USB stick and I have installed  Linux Mint, Ubuntu, Fedora Games, Windows 7 and Windows 8 successfully from it. I also have three different anti-malware tools and Parted Magic in this single USB stick.

Debian is the only one giving problems. When I boot from debian-live-8.6.0-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso I get the error `"The CD_ROM does not seem to contain a valid 'Release' file, or that file could not be read correctly"` right after selecting language. Same error occurs in Install or Graphical install. Live desktop runs perfectly. "Install Debian jessie" shortcut does nothing or flashes some window so fast, I cannot read it.

How do I get Debian installer to work from YUMI multiboot installer?

Answer (score 2):

According to Debian [handbook](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch04s03.html.en#usb-copy-flexible) you should write your image " to the whole-disk device and not a partition"

> **Important**
>
> The image must be written to the whole-disk device and not a partition, e.g. /dev/sdb and not /dev/sdb1. Do not use tools like unetbootin which alter the image.